# MaxLength="255" property does not seem to be working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textBox field with a MaxLength set to 255. I can enter more than 255 characters in the textbox. I was expecting there to be a 255 character limit.Is there any way to control this? Do I need to use the code behind? Can we control this with a RequiredFieldValidator?

here is the code in the .aspx

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentaire" runat="server" Width="600px" MaxLength="255" TextMode="MultiLine" 
 Height="90px" style="overflow:hidden" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You can use a `CustomValidator` or `RegularExpressionValidator`. Additionally you can use  a javascript method that restricts the number of characters.

Comment: http://www.codegod.com/aspnet-textbox-maxlength-in-multiline-mode-AID297.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MaxLength doesn't apply when you have TextMode="Multiline".

when you use `<asp:TextBox  TextMode="Multiline">`, a `<textarea>` is rendered to the page. TextArea tags didn't support a maxlength attribute until recently (html5). Therefore, when this feature was initially designed, Microsoft ignored the MaxLength attribute in Multiline mode.

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxLength` property does not function while the `TextBox` is in multi-line mode.  This needs to be made single line or needs a different enforcement technique (like using javascript to hook a key press event)